# C++ CTreeCtrl, how to edit only one item of a tree

Tags: c++, tree, mfc

Is there any way to make editable `CTreeCtrl` items that are fit in exact condition, not all of tree items.

If I set `TVS_EDITLABELS`, all tree items can be changed by right button click

```
CViewTree m_ModelTree;   //  CViewTree based on CTreeCtrl
const DWORD dwViewStyle = WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | TVS_HASLINES | TVS_LINESATROOT | TVS_HASBUTTONS | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | TVS_EDITLABELS;
    
    if (!m_ModelTree.Create(dwViewStyle, rectDummy, this, IDC_TREEMODEL))
    {
        TRACE0(_T("Failed to create Class View\n"));
        return -1;      // fail to create
    }
```

And I need to edit only exact type of nodes. Something like this:

```
HTREEITEM item = m_ModelTree.GetSelectedItem();
auto it = theApp.TreeMap.find(item);
if (it == theApp.TreeMap.end()) return;
if(it->type == tree_node_type::indexes)
    m_ModelTree.EditLabel(hItem);
else
   //FORBID EDIT
```

Or maybe is there a way to forbid edit lable with `TV_INSERTSTRUCT` on the `InsertItem` step...?

```
TV_INSERTSTRUCT tvinsert;
m_ModelTree.InsertItem(&tvinsert);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard [Tree View](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/Controls/tree-view-control-reference) control with the `TVS_EDITLABELS` style allows clients to control, at run time, whether any given item can be edited. This is offered in the form of a [`TVN_BEGINLABELEDIT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/Controls/tvn-beginlabeledit) notification sent to the control's parent, where the return value determines whether editing should be canceled.

The MFC entry [Tree Control Label Editing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/tree-control-label-editing) in the documentation provides details:

> When label editing begins, a tree control sends a `TVN_BEGINLABELEDIT` notification message. **By processing this notification, you can allow editing of some labels and prevent editing of others.** Returning 0 allows editing, and returning nonzero prevents it.

To receive `TVN_BEGINLABELEDIT` notifications, the control parent (presumably a dialog or regular window) must have an entry in its message map that wires the notification to a callback function. The [`ON_NOTIFY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/tn061-on-notify-and-wm-notify-messages) macro is the most convenient way to go about this:

```cpp
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyDialog, CDialogEx)
    // ...
    ON_NOTIFY(TVN_BEGINLABELEDIT, IDC_TREEMODEL, OnTCBeginLabelEdit)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

The `OnTCBeginLabelEdit` callback must have the following signature:

```cpp
afx_msg void OnTCBeginLabelEdit(NMHDR* pNotifyStruct, LRESULT* result);
```

Its implementation is where the logic to decide whether editing should be canceled goes:

```cpp
void CMyDialog::OnTCBeginLabelEdit(NMHDR* pNotifyStruct, LRESULT* result) {
    // The TVN_BEGINLABELEDIT notification sends an NMTVDISPINFO structure
    auto const& disp_info = *reinterpret_cast<NMTVDISPINFO*>(pNotifyStruct);
    // Get the target item
    auto const current_item = disp_info.item.hItem;

    // Implement the logic here
    bool do_cancel = ...;

    // Pass the decision through result
    *result = do_cancel;
}
```

The above assumes that the tree view control is a child of a dialog called `CMyDialg` that derives from `CDialogEx`. Those are the only parts that need to be adjusted accordingly.

Comment: Side questions: why did you cast the pointer in the manner that you did?bAnd why is it ok to go from `bool` to `LRESULT` without the need of a cast?

Comment: @AndrewTruckle The callback receives an argument of type `NMHDR*,` but this notification sends an `NTVDISPINFO*`, hence the cast. I then dereference the pointer and bind it to a `const` reference for robustness: It prevents accidental modification and is always valid (unlike a pointer). Going from `bool` to `LRESULT` (i.e. `LONG_PTR`) follows the rules of [implicit conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion). `false` is converted to 0, and `true` is converted to 1 as the destination type. Curiously, this follows different rules for 32-bit and 64-bit targets.

Comment: The final statement might be confusing. The net result is the same for 32-bit and 64-bit targets: A value of type `LRESULT` that's either 0 or 1. Just the way to get there differs: 32-bit exercises the rules of "integral promotion", whereas a 64-bit build follows the rules of "integral conversion". The rules are complex because `int` is rather special.